# method to convert color image to grayscale image

Tags: image, syntax-error, bufferedimage

I have some error on the follow code and i don't know why i get errorenter image description here [image]

```
// A method to convert color image to grayscale image

public static BufferedImage toGrayScale(Image img) {
I        // Convert image from type Image to BufferedImage
    BufferedImage bufImg = convert(img);

    // Scan through each row of the image
    for (int j = 0; j < bufImg.getHeight(); j++) {

        // Scan through each columns of the image
        for (int i = 0; i < bufImg.getWidth(); i++) {
            // Returns an integer pixel in the default RGB color model
            int values = bufImg.getRGB(i, j);

            // Convert the single integer pixel value to RGB color
            Color oldColor = new Color(values);
            int red = oldColor.getRed();

    // get red value
            int green = oldColor.getGreen();

    // get green value
            int blue = oldColor.getBlue();

    // get blue value
            // Convert RGB to grayscale using formula
            // gray = 0.299 * R + 0.587 * G + 0.114 * B
            double grayVal = 0.299 * red + 0.587 * green + 0.114 * blue;

            // Assign each channel of RGB with the same value
            Color newColor = new Color((int) grayVal, (int) grayVal, (int) grayVal);

            // Get back the integer representation of RGB color
            // and assign it back to the original position
            bufImg.setRGB(i, j, newColor.getRGB());
        }
    }
    // return back the resulting image in BufferedImage type
    return bufImg;
}
```

Comment: Please don't post code as an image and avoid unnessary line feeds.

Comment: image is show the error part below of the image have the code

Answer (score 2):

There is a random `I` hanging on the left of the `// Convert image from type Image to BufferedImage` comment.

[image]

Comment: @TLam also, please accept this answer so others may find it useful.